# SwiftMailer - Adding PHP elements to the Message Body

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to make the body of the mail with this [huge concatenation]

```
$body='<table  border=1>'.'<tr>'.'<th>Description</th>'.'<th>Quantity</th>'.'<th>Cost</th>'.'</tr>';
for($x=0;$x<=$length-1;$x++)
    {
    $body .='<tr>'.'<td>'.$json2[$x]["description"].'</td>'.'<td>'.$json2[$x]["qty"].'</td>'.'<td>'.$json2[$x]["cost"].'</td>'.'</tr>';
    }

$body.='</table>';
```

And send it using Swift Mailer

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Thanks for your Order')
->setFrom(array('abc@gmail.com' => 'Sender')) 
->setTo(array('xzy@gmail.com' => 'Receiver Name')) 
->setBody($body,'html');
```

The mail is received successfully but I the table is not seen.

For Feroz

```
 $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('DialSwap - Thanks for your Order')
 ->setFrom(array('rorrykeys2@gmail.com' => 'DialSwap')) 
 ->setTo(array('rorrykeys@gmail.com' => 'Receiver Name')) 
 ->setBody($body,'text/html');
 $headers = $message->getHeaders();
 $headers->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

Comment: Look at your message source and see if data is there. Some times this kind of behavior is caused by broken headers of message.

Comment: just checked it up. It attaches the contents of $body as a file which i am able to download. What should be done , for it to work.

Comment: Yes, that means message structure is broken. You should read manual of SwiftMailer more carefully. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html` is not a valid `Content-Type`:

```
->setBody($body,'html');
```

You probably want `text/html`.

You can find some usage examples in the [Creating Messages](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) chapter.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the headers like below

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$headers = $message->getHeaders();

$headers->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

Comment: i do not think you got my question. I want to send a table as a message which is contained in the $body variable.

Comment: if you dont see any table in your received message, and raw HTML data it means you mail headers are not set. So you have to mention the mail server that this message is an HTML type message

Comment: is this okay? $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
 
 
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('DialSwap - Thanks for your Order')
    ->setFrom(array('rorrykeys2@gmail.com' => 'DialSwap')) 
    ->setTo(array('rorrykeys@gmail.com' => 'Receiver Name')) 
    ->setBody($body,'text/html');
    $headers = $message->getHeaders();

 $headers->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

Comment: why dont you simply test it by sending the mail :?

Comment: what are getting in your mail?

Comment: got it feroz. thank you. Like you said it was the header problem. just changed html to text/html. thanks for the help!